# Custom CacheInterceptor is being overridden by default Spring's CacheInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I've implemented a custom `CacheInterceptor` which allows evicting the cache by wildcard:

```
public class CustomCacheInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomCacheInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    protected void doEvict(Cache cache, Object key) {
        try {
            // evict cache
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            getErrorHandler().handleCacheEvictError(ex, cache, key);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to make it working:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomProxyCachingConfiguration extends ProxyCachingConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomProxyCachingConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public CacheInterceptor cacheInterceptor() {
        LOGGER.info("Creating custom cache interceptor");

        CacheInterceptor interceptor = new CustomCacheInterceptor();
        interceptor.setCacheOperationSources(cacheOperationSource());
        if (this.cacheResolver != null) {
            interceptor.setCacheResolver(this.cacheResolver);
        } else if (this.cacheManager != null) {
            interceptor.setCacheManager(this.cacheManager);
        }
        if (this.keyGenerator != null) {
            interceptor.setKeyGenerator(this.keyGenerator);
        }
        if (this.errorHandler != null) {
            interceptor.setErrorHandler(this.errorHandler);
        }
        return interceptor;
    }
}
```

The problem is that my `CustomCacheInterceptor` is being overridden by default one:

```
Overriding user-defined bean definition for bean 'cacheInterceptor' with a framework-generated bean definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=customProxyCachingConfiguration; factoryMethodName=cacheInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/package/test/CustomProxyCachingConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration; factoryMethodName=cacheInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class]]
```

I've tried different ways to solve this problem:

1) Tried to exclude `ProxyCachingConfiguration` with `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ProxyCachingConfiguration.class))` and provide own `BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor` - didn't help

2) Tried `@Primary` but it seems to be working only at injection time - not my case

3) Tried to choose different name of the bean - "customCacheInterceptor" - in this case my custom class is not being invoked

4) Tried to add `@DependsOn("cacheOperationSource")` which is located in `ProxyCachinConfiguration` to make Spring loading `ProxyCachinConfiguration` before my config - didn't help

**The most strange thing** is that sometimes my config wins during application start and everything works fine

How can I override default `CacheInterceptor` with my `CustomCacheInterceptor`?

Spring Boot Version - 2.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: Such low-level override of this feature is not really expected. The configuration is low-level and beans are configured with role infrastructure so they are not supposed to be post-processed either. Rather than hacking a core feature, please roll out your own annotation and create your own interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Spring bean overriding is messy and should be avoided. Last bean definition for given name creates the actual bean but there is no predictable order between definitions as it depends on multiple factors e.g. Groovy vs XML vs JavaConfig.

It would be safer to exclude the `ProxyCachingConfiguration` configuration class from your context `@ComponentScan` and redefine it yourself, providing both `CacheInterceptor` and  `BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor`.

If your goal is to just replace the advice set in the default `BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor` bean you can define a new [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) bean and call `setAdvice()` during `postProcessBeforeInitialization()`.

Comment: My goal is to make `CustomCacheInterceptor` working

Comment: Define "working", it would depend how you use it e.g. do you auto-wire it by type.

Comment: Replace default `CacheInterceptor` with my own

Comment: I've tried to add `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ProxyCachingConfiguration.class))` on my main class and it didn't help

Comment: By default Spring invokes his own `CacheInterceptor` when proxying methods annotated with `@Cacheable`. I want to change the behaviour of this default `CacheInterceptor` - that's why I've created my own class